# Why am I having error in createToken() in laravel Sanctum?

Tags: laravel, cookies

I have a project react frontend and laravel API. I am trying to implement Laravel Sanctum with cookie in my code:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function registration(Request $request) {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
    
    // Check if the email is already taken
    $existinguser = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();
    if($existinguser) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Email already in use'], 400);
    }
    
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $credentials['name'];
    $user->email = $credentials['email'];
    $user->password = bcrypt($credentials['password']);
    $user->save();
    return response()->json(['message'=>'User created successfully']);
}


public function signin(Request $request) {
    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $user = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();
        if ($user && Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user->password)) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $token = $user->createToken('api-token')->plainTextToken;
            $cookie = cookie('jwt', $token, 60*24); //name, token variable, validity duration
            return response(['user' => $user])->withCookie($cookie);
        }
    }
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Email or password is incorrect'], 401);
}

public function loggedinuser() {
    return Auth::user();
}

public function signout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Logged Out'], 200);
}
```

In signin function, I am getting an error with `createToken` saying:

> 'Undefined method createToken'.

If I don't have `$user = Auth::user();` line, it works just fine, but if I don't have that line, I don't think user is not authenticated user according to the Laravel Sanctum. I am not sure. I might be wrong.

Also is my auth correct in `signin` and `signout`?

After logged in, I am trying to add authenticated `userID` to the products that user put into his cart in `addtoCart` function which I will create. Am I on the right path? If not, is there any advice on how to do that?

Comment: To use createToken, you need to ensure you have installed and configured Sanctum properly. You should have the Laravel\Sanctum\SanctumServiceProvider registered in your config/app.php and have the api guard configured to use Sanctum in your config/auth.php.